# Jquery combobox dropdown option selections

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, combobox

I have been at this one for a day or two...

I can't seem to get the values that are being selected in the dropdown to 'do' anything.

### The HTML

```
<select id="combobox">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

### The Js/Jquery to get my values to do something

```
function displayVals() {
        var skillValues = $('#combobox').val();
        $('ul#list').append('<li>x</li>' + skillValues);
    }

    $('select').change( displayVals );
    displayVals();
```

I used the following link as the 'basis' for what I am trying to do.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

when the select item is being defined by the 'combobox' from jqueryUI it stops doing the thing that makes the < li>'s. I imagine that for some reason the < option>'s are not being selected.

So I am trying to get each selection to show up in a < ul> when they are selected, and then maybe be deleted with a click event.

Thanks in advance all, any help would be welcome!

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/tPs42/ this is what it is supposed to do right now, so as you can see it works with a regular dropdown selector.

EDIT: okay, I got it to do what i wanted it to do...

```
$(function() {
  $( "#combobox" ).combobox({
    select: function displayVals() {
        var skillValues = $('#combobox').val();
        $('ul#list').append('<li><a href="" name="remove">x</a></li>' + skillValues);
    }
        });
    });
    $('select').change( displayVals );
    displayVals();

    $('a[name=remove]').click(removeItem);
```

that did the trick for me to do what i wanted to do.

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/73Vbz/

Comment: @Krishna I put that one up to illustrate what it is supposed to to, the problem is when I add the jqueryUI 'combobox' to the equation the script won't select the options.